# identifying xpath from Ext JS application

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automated a application designed in `Ext Js`, `xpath` identification is become complex. Please help in getting the `xpath` for the below scenario.

For a dropdown having a set of names, need to select a name from the list available.

I'm using a mouse action to locate the drop down name and then `moveToElement` particular element in the List of menu present.

For example If the menu is containing a list of names like, `Abi`, `Ashwini Asha`, `Ashwini`, `Diva`.

Using parameterizing I'm able to select the names from the menu.

But when I need to select `Ashwini` from the menu ,since `Ashwini Asha` is already present in the menu , `Ashwini Asha` object gets clicked.

`contains()` is not working here. Which function should I use?

The below is the code  which am using :

html :

```
<div id="combo-1023-inputWrap" class="x-form-text-wrap x-form-  text-wrap-default" role="presentation" data-ref="inputWrap">
  <input id="combo-1023-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-text-default " type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false" role="combobox" value="Triton" name="selectedName" size="1" data-ref="inputEl" data-componentid="combo-1023">

  ......

  <li>------------ Ashwini Asha</li>
  <li>------------ Ashwini</li>
</div>
```

to click on the menu :

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedName']"))).click().perform();
```

to load the data in the menu :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibiltyOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'"+NameParameter+"')]")));
```

click the object :

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'"+NameParameter+"')]"))).click().perform();
```

Let me know how to select the name `Ashwini` alone?

Thanks

Comment: I think in my case i dnt think contains(),Starts-with(),ends-with() will work,..

Answer (score 2):

No need to use contains in your `xpath`. Go for exact match of the name.

```
 By.xpath("//li[text()='"+NameParameter+"']")
```

or

```
 By.xpath("//li[.='"+NameParameter+"']")
```

Comment: What are the dots prefixed in the <li> tag? Can you give the complete source in the div tag which contains these <li> elements?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you could use:

`Driver.Instance.findElements(...`

This would return an array in which you could just iterate and perform actions on based on the `.text` of the element.

Comment: But the elements are not in array , they are justed listed as list menu

Comment: Right, but using this would take all the list menu items and return them as a collection of elements - then you could cherry pick which ones you'd like to interact with by doing something like `list_of_elememts[1].text` and that would return "------------ Ashwini"